# Jenkins Remote Deployments

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We're trying to setup Jenkins, but we are having a couple issues.

We have a "Jenkins Server" (Master) and have connected it to Fisheye.  Jenkins is able to get the Git repo and run the tests.

Is there some kind of built in process for Jenkins to give it capabilites to SSH into a server and run commands like "git pull origin master" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is ssh capabilities in Jenkins. You can add a build step for either running SSH or sending files over SSH (you have to define target server in config). Theres also a post build plugin for sending artifacts over ssh which can be used to also execute remote commands.

I'd recommend a book by John Smart which covers Jenkins setup. Its at http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide

Comment: Is it possible to deploy to several servers not creating separate job for each server?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the [SSH Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin). This will let you define SSH servers in your global configuration, and then define commands to be run before and after the build.

Comment: Is it possible to deploy to several servers not creating separate job for each server?